# How can I extract meta tags from HTML in a bash/awk script?

Tags: bash, command-line, awk, metadata

I have a working Bash script to extract title tags. I need help with an AWK field separator for extracting meta tags from HTML, like these:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="key1, key2, key3">
```

my script works to extract title, but `meta name` doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
for LINE in `cat htmls.txt`

do
   echo $LINE
   awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="<title>|</title>";RS=EOF} {print $2}' $LINE |
   awk '{ if (NF > 0) printf("%s\n", $0); }'
done
```

I guess I need a regex solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

first install [xml2](http://www.ofb.net/~egnor/xml2/) e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install xml2

wget -q -O - http://www.latin.fm | xml2 | grep meta | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

Output

```
@property=og:title
@content=Latin FM
...
```

Comment: Eric, thanks for your comment. My desktop is Mac OS, I have xml2 littered all over my OS plus the framework (checked in Xcode) but can't figure out how to use it (execute xml2).

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
$ awk '/meta name/{ gsub(/.*meta name=\042|\042.*/,"");print }' file
keywords
```

To get from website, use `wget`

```
wget -O- -q $url | awk '/meta name/{ gsub(/.*meta name=\042|\042.*/,"");print }'
```