# Extract info out of html via bash

Tags: html, linux, bash, parsing, awk

i am trying to write a bashscript that can extract info out of a large html file. I need this to automatically download the latest newspaper every morning :).
To download the latest newspaper I have to know the ID of it. To get it, I have to parse the link, that points to it.
I managed to extract the line, that holds the id with awk with

```
awk '/show.php\?id=/' index.html
```

and get

```
<a href="show.php?id=914826">Latest Newspaper</a>
```

So what I need out of this line is "914826". This is where I am stuck... I don't think I can use awk to extract not the whole line, but a fragment.

Looking forward to your answers.
Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: Check out xml2 command as in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7058658/78602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This complete `awk` command should work. For lines that match the regexp, split in `=` and `"`. Splitting like this in your example line:

- First field would be: `<a href=`
- Second field: [blank]
- Third field: `show.php?id`
- Fourth field: `914826`
- And fifth field: `>Latest Newspaper</a>`

So print the fourth one (`arr[4]`):

```
awk '
    /show.php\?id=/ { 
        split( $0, arr, /[="]/ ); 
        print arr[4] 
    }
' index.html
```

Comment: Much simpler: `awk -F '[="]' '/show.php\?id=/ {print $4}' index.html` AWK gives you the first split for free.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -o 'id=[0-9]*'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '<a href="show.php?id=914826">Latest Newspaper</a>' | grep -o 'id=[0-9]*'
id=914826
```

The same you can do with perl or sed:

```
$ echo '<a href="show.php?id=914826">Latest Newspaper</a>' | perl -pe 's/.*id=([0-9]*).*/$1/'
914826
```

Comment: I will use grep way. Thank you very much. Are there any tutorials you can recommend? As a Java developer I find it very hard to find valuable information about bash in general

Comment: The ABS is mediocre quality. Use [Greg Wooledge's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) instead.